# bundle exec jekyll serve stopped working: can't modify frozen String: "3.1.3" (FrozenError)

Tags: ruby, terminal, rubygems, jekyll, github-pages

(Ruby V 3.1.3, Mac OS Big Sur):
`bundle install` and `bundle exec jekyll serve` were working a few days ago. I'm not sure what changed, I cloned a repository to a different path so I can edit locally and this error began occurring. Tried to run both commands today and I receive:

```
bundle exec jekyll serve
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/version.rb:191:in `strip!': can't modify frozen String: "3.1.3" (FrozenError)
```

I'm new to working with Ruby and GitHub, what causes this frozen error? Have I installed Ruby incorrectly and if so can I uninstall Ruby and reinstall? Thank you!

Trying to view local repository in my githb-pages build using jekyll. Tried to bundle `exec jekyll serve` which was working a few days ago, and now I get `can't modify frozen String: "3.1.3" (FrozenError)`

I tried `jekyll -v` and now I am getting

```
/usr/local/bin/jekyll:11:in `<main>': undefined method `use_gemdeps' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)

Gem.use_gemdeps
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I have tried `bundle`
and I get the same

```
can't modify frozen String: "3.1.3" (FrozenError)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction or where to start here?

Comment: *were working a few days ago* Obviously something changed. When seeking assistance you should explain what has changed. Please don't ask others to try to guess at what you may have changed. Additionally, it's useful to include versions of libraries when you are seeking assistance, so knowing the Ruby version is helpful but not knowing the versions of jekyll or bundler is not helpful. Also running `jekyll -v` isn't helpful; you need to run `bundle exec jekyll -v` because `jekyll` points to `/usr/local/bin` instead of the rbenv shims path it should point to with `bundle exec`.

Comment: Thank you this is super helpful. My apologies as I am new to coding. I ran bundle exec jekyll -v to point to the right path and I still get 
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/version.rb:191:in `strip!': can't modify frozen String: "3.1.3" (FrozenError). I guess my primary question is can I reinstall ruby or uninstall 3.1.3 to fix this error?

Comment: Yes, you can remove and reinstall rbenv and Ruby completely. https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#uninstalling-rbenv